# Node.js net module documentation error

Tags: node.js, sockets

Reading the Node.js documentation for the `net` module I can see the text used for `net.connect` and `net.createConnection` is exactly the same. Indeed the example used in `net.createConnection` uses `net.connect`.

Is this an error in the documentation? Is there any difference between `net.connect` and `net.createConnection`?

Thanks.

Comment: They are the exact same function as @lxe mentioned, `net.createConnection()` is the older of the two and more wordy. I've submitted a PR to fix the example [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Node.js source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L61) they do the same exact thing:

```
exports.connect = exports.createConnection = function() {
```